# awk won't print new line characters

Tags: awk, newline

I am using the below code to change an existing awk script so that I can add more and more cases with a simple command.

```
echo `awk '{if(/#append1/){print "pref'"$1"'=0\n" $0 "\n"} else{print $0 "\n"}}' tf.a
```

note that the first print is `"pref'"$1"'=0\n"` so it is referring to the variable `$1` in its environment, not in `awk` itself.

The command `./tfb.a "c"` should change the code from:

```
BEGIN{
#append1
}
...
```

to:

```
BEGIN{
prefc=0
#append1
}
...
```

However, it gives me everything on one line.

Does anyone know why this is?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you take `awk` right out of the equation you can see what's going on:

```
# Use a small test file instead of an awk script
$ cat xxx
hello
there
$ echo `cat xxx`
hello there
$ echo "`cat xxx`"
hello
there
$ echo "$(cat xxx)"
hello
there
$
```

The backtick operator expands the output into shell "words" too soon.  You could play around with the `$IFS` variable in the shell (yikes), or you could just use double-quotes.

If you're running a modern `sh` (e.g. `ksh` or `bash`, not the "classic" Bourne `sh`), you may also want to use the `$()` syntax (it's easier to find the matching start/end delimiter).

Answer (score 2):

do it like this. pass the variable from shell to awk properly using -v

```
#!/bin/bash
toinsert="$1"
awk -v toinsert=$toinsert '
/#append1/{
    $0="pref"toinsert"=0\n"$0
}
{print}
' file > temp
mv temp file
```

output

```
$ cat file
BEGIN{
#append1
}

$ ./shell.sh c
BEGIN{
prefc=0
#append1
}
```

Comment: Does it matter if `awk` is wrapped in `echo`?

Comment: lose the echo and try again. seriously, i don't know what is the echo for. See my output. Otherwise, show more details of your code and describe what you want clearly.

Comment: @Mechko: the echo is what's causing the output to print on one line. Eliminate it as **ghostdog74** suggests or do something like this: `echo "$(awk stuff)"` - wrapping it in double quotes will preserve the newlines.

Comment: ah ok.  I do need the echo because there's a bunch of other things that need printing out.

btw, I now have a fully functional markdown parser with the option to have users define their own markdown macros, if anyone wants it.  I'm going to work on an installation script tomorrow.